# How can I delete a Label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I click a button, it should write text under it and the text should disappear after few seconds.

I don't know how to code that. What I have tried so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import time


window = Tk()
window.title("Button")
window.geometry("500x300")

def buttonclick():
    tex = Label(text="You clicked the button")
    tex.pack()
    time.sleep(5)
    tex.destroy()

but = Button(text="Click me!", command=buttonclick)
but.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.after()` method to destroy the label after fixed period of time.

The following example will delete the label after 3 seconds:

```
from tkinter import *
import time


window = Tk()
window.title("Button")
window.geometry("500x300")

def buttonclick():
    tex = Label(text="You clicked the button")
    tex.pack()
    tex.after(3000, tex.destroy)

but = Button(text="Click me!", command=buttonclick)
but.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image: destroy label after 3 seconds]

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct for the most part. The reason why it doesn't appear to be working is that there is nothing telling the window to update after adding the text. A simple fix would be to add `window.update()` when you create the label.

The Code should look like:

```
from tkinter import *
import time


window = Tk()
window.title("Button")
window.geometry("500x300")

def buttonclick():
    tex = Label(text="You clicked the button")
    tex.pack()
    window.update()
    time.sleep(5)
    tex.destroy()
    window.update()

but = Button(text="Click me!", command=buttonclick)
but.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: even though you call `update`, this will still cause the UI to freeze for five seconds.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yea, I was going for a solution keeping as much of the code as it is. `.after()` as mentioned above is the best solution without going into multithreading.